# alias -g '${1+"$@"}'='"$@"', what does it do?

Tags: shell, zsh, alias

Most makefile have this strange set of symbols `'${1+"$@"}'`. $@ is the makefile target filename. But why does, people try to use the complex symbol like `'${1+"$@"}'`?

Comment: What does this have to do with make? `alias` isn't something you'd typically find in a makefile.

Comment: The title includes "curlies" now (factually wrong) due to site redesign, related discussion on meta: https://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/site-design-updates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of `${1+"$@"}` for portability.

[POSIX defined $@](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) would expand to nothing if there're no positional arguments. But original Bourne shell (`/bin/sh` in Solaris 10 and before) would expand it to empty string `""`. Using `${1+"$@"}` is a work around for this, since when `"$@"` only expanded if `$1` was set.

Unfortunately, this construct doesn't work in zsh 3.x and pre 4.3, because zsh [performs word splitting on `${1+"$@"}`](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2002/msg00542.html) in sh emulation mode ([shwordsplit](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-SHWORDSPLIT) was set):

```
$ set -- '1 2'
$ for i in ${1+"$@"}; do echo $i; done
1
2
```

`"$@"` is handled properly:

```
$ set -- '1 2'
$ for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done
1 2
```

So `alias -g '${1+"$@"}'='"$@"'` makes sure word splitting never performed when using `${1+"$@"}`. This allows the construct `${1+"$@"}` to be used in zsh, as it will be replaced by `"$@"` before expansion (you must use exactly the character string `${1+"$@"}`, with no leading or trailing word characters).

---

Another work around you can do, is completely ignore using `"$@"` if there're no positional arguments, by checking `$#`:

```
case $# in
  (0) func ;;
  (*) func "$@" ;;
esac
```

It took more works, but completely portable.